I did a Logistic Regression Model in R but I got a straight line instead of an S-curve
This is the string of code I used for the regression model but I got a straight line instead of a sigmoid curve

Help would be greatly appreciated. It's the first time I'm using the program and I need all the help I can get.
ENGR2280$century_in_less_than_30_overs = ifelse(ENGR2280$`over for century`< 30, 1, 0)

model = glm(`Win/Lose` ~ century_in_less_than_30_overs, data = ENGR2280, family = binomial)
prediction = predict(model, type = "response")
accuracy = mean(ifelse(prediction >= 0.5, 1, 0) == ENGR2280$`Win/Lose`)
print(paste("Accuracy:", accuracy))

summary(model)
plot(ENGR2280$century_in_less_than_30_overs, ENGR2280$`Win/Lose`,
     xlab = "Century in Less Than 30 Overs", ylab = "Win/Lose",
     main = "Logistic Regression Model", 
     pch = 19, col = "blue")
curve(predict(model, data.frame(century_in_less_than_30_overs = x), type = "response"),
      add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)


We don't have your data, but that plot looks reasonable, assuming that the probabilities are pretty close to 0.5.  In that region the sigmoid is pretty straight.

You will not be able to get a sigmoid curve with your current data because you only have one predictor: century_in_less_than_30_overs, which only has only two values 0 and 1. To connect two points, you will get a straight line.
